# Parsing Json Object using soap in android

Tags: java, android, json, soap

I am trying to parse soap response which is json object from service.

Facing below exception. Please help.

```
soap Service code:

public JSONObject getHotelList(String location){
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    System.out.println("it is part of webservice and getHotelList");
    con = db.getConnection();
    String hotel = null;
    try{
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "select * from androidtest.hotel_location_list_table where Location=\""+location+"\"";
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next()){
        //hotel = rs.getString("HotelName");
        hotellist.add(rs.getString("HotelName"));
    }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("hotelList-->>"+hotellist);
    obj.put(location, hotellist);

    ArrayList<String> out = (ArrayList<String>) obj.get(location);
    System.out.println("out-->>"+out);

    return obj;
}

Client code in android:

    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    try{
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
        request.addProperty("location", "Chennai");
        //envelope.bodyOut = request;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
           HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
           try {
               transport.call(NAMESPACE + SOAP_ACTION_PREFIX + METHOD, envelope);
             } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           SoapObject resultSOAP= (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
           resp=resultSOAP.toString();
             System.out.println("responce from service -->>"+resp);


             JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(resultSOAP);
             JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
             System.out.println("jsonarraylength-->>"+jarray.length());
             for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){
                 obj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                 System.out.println(obj.getString("Chennai"));
             }
     }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return al;
}
```

Getting below exception..can anyone help

> org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject at
>   org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:116) at
>   com.example.googleapi.AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(AsyncTaskRunner.java:66)
>   at
>   com.example.googleapi.AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(AsyncTaskRunner.java:1)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

I am in need of sending jsonobject from service and parsing at client side. I am using simple json 1.1.1. jar file for this.

Comment: can you paste response from service

Comment: responce from service -->>Map{item=anyType{key=Chennai; value=anyType{value=Park Hotel; value=Hilton Hotel; value=Alot; }; }; }

Comment: Can anyone help here?

Comment: You are trying to parse a response which is not in Json format. If you check the response in [Jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) response is not validated. Since this response is not too long you can treat it as string and get things out of your meaning.